# Помогите с регулярным выражением на javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать регулярное выражение, которое бы находило слово: «Элемент» (слово может вообще любым быть, суть как раз в его поиске) среди следующего набора тэгов (Сверху и снизу еще и другой html код поэтому поставил троеточие):

```
...
<a href="main/url.html" class="word_state" data-pjax="">Элемент</a><span> - </span>
...
```

Еще есть такой момент, что в документе много ссылок , но нужны те у которых в адресе href есть “main”

Мои наработки:
(?<="/main/.......(не знаю как поставить n колличество символов)>)(.*)(?=</a><span>) Есть еще проблема, что если есть еще ссылка с окончанием как у этой, то захватывает программа последнюю, а нужно эту

Comment: `console.log( [...document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="main"]')].filter(e => /^\s*элемент\s*$/i.test(e.textContent) )` - чем не устроил?)

Comment: А если поиск идет из внешнего источника, например текст html хранится в переменной, а не в документе

Comment: `let div = document.createElement("div"); div.innerHTML = html_строка_из_переменной;` → `console.log( [...div.querySelectorAll(ляляля)] )` — если конечно источник доверенный, и не будет содержать вредоносного кода*

Comment: А еще такой момент, слово элемент может вообще другим быть, смысл в том, что бы узнать что за слово, как я понял из примера идет проверка на то, что слово является Элемент, но оно может быть другим

Comment: Потом попробовал ваш пример, мне console вернула пустой массив, вот мой код: let dat=`<a href="main/url.html" class="word_state" data-pjax="">Элемент</a><span> - </span>`


let div = document.createElement("div"); 
div.innerHTML = dat; 
console.log( [div.querySelectorAll('a[href^="main"]')].filter(e => /^\s*Элемент\s*$/i.test(e.textContent)))

Comment: Приведите однозначные примеры текстов и что в них надо найти в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/<a[^>]*?\shref="[^"]*main.*?".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/` (Ой!)

>>> https://regex101.com/ может помочь с разбором регулярок.

`[^>]` — всё что угодно, кроме символа `>`

`*?` — ноль или много раз, до тех пор, пока не дойдет до

`\shref="` href с обязательным `\s` пробелом перед ним, в котором встречается `main`

`[^"]` гарантирует, что main найдется менно внутри href, пока кавычка не закрыта.

```js
let test = `
  + <a href="main/url.html" class="word_state" data-pjax="">111</a><span></span>  
  + <br><a href="/main/url.html">222</a><span></span>  
  - <br><a href="#" data-href="main">333</a><span></span>  
  - <br><a href="#">подвох href="main"</a><span></span>  
  - <br><a href="main/url.html" data-подвох="<a>Маловероятный подвох</a>">444</a>
`;

console.log( getLinkContents(test) );

function getLinkContents(str) {
  let reg = /<a[^>]*?\shref="[^"]*main.*?".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/;
  let g_reg = new RegExp(reg, "g");

  return ( str.match(g_reg) || [] ).map(a => a.match(reg)[1]);
  // Сначала находит все совпадения (флажок `g`)
  // Потом через map достает только нужный кусок: всё, что попалось внутри скобок (.*?)

  // Особенность логического оператора || 'ИЛИ':
  // Если match вернет null (в логическом контексте - false),
  // возьмется второй [] пустой массив, он и вернется: map с ним ничего не сделает.
}
```

Но при условии, что HTML-строка прилетает из доверенного источника, или вы предварительно поудаляли всякие `<img onerror="Бесконечный цикл">`, надежнее будет использовать готовые методы для чтения:

```js
let test = `
  + <a href="main/url.html" class="word_state" data-pjax="">111</a><span></span>  
  + <br><a href="/main/url.html">222</a><span></span>  
  - <br><a href="#" data-href="main">333</a><span></span>  
  - <br><a href="#">подвох href="main"</a><span></span>  
  + <br><a href="main/url.html" data-подвох="<a>Маловероятный подвох</a>">444</a>
`;

console.log( getLinkContents(test) );

function getLinkContents(str) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = str;
  
  return [...div.querySelectorAll('a[href*="main"]')].map(a => a.textContent);
}
```

Где `a[href*="main"]` - комбинация [CSS-селекторов](https://webref.ru/css#selectors)

Но querySelectorAll возвращает коллекцию элементов. У него нет метода map().

А это `...` — ["Spread" оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax): Добавляет все элементы в настоящий массив, у которого есть встроенный [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: А можно как-то отдельно взять нулевой элемент из массива, ну просто получается все длинной строкой через map, например если захочу отдельно первый элемент или просто длину массива узнать

Comment: @Mikhail `console.log( getLinkContents(test)[0] );` — первый, `console.log( getLinkContents(test).length );` — длина, `getLinkContents(test).slice(-1)[0]` — последний)